# How to call another project's method from windows service project( same solution ) c# asp.net

Tags: c#, couchbase

I have several projects and one windows service project C#. I want to using static method of A1 project, from windows service project. Of course i added reference but i can't access that method. That method does access to Couchbase(Nosql).For example: Create, Insert, Update etc... If you have some experience, please help me.

```
 class Trigger_class // this class in windows service project 
{
    static double scheduledHour = 12;
    static double scheduleMinute = 42;
    static DateTime scheduleTime;
    //static TimeSpan _ScheduledRunningTime = new TimeSpan(16,00,00);
    System.Timers.Timer Timer = null;
    double interval = 10;
    public Trigger_class()
    {
        scheduleTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(scheduledHour).AddMinutes(scheduleMinute);
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
        Timer.AutoReset = true;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Timer.Start();
        Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        if (scheduleTime < DateTime.Now)
        {
            scheduleTime = scheduleTime.AddHours(24);
            mix_plan.computeNextDayPlan(); // <-- This is A1's static method 

        }
```

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong assuming the class name of A1 is mix-plan. Do you get a compilation error or a run-time error? Is the static method public?

Comment: mix_plan is public class and computeNextDayPlan is  --> public static void computeNextDayPlan() . There are no errors

Comment: What do you mean "i can't access that method"? during runtime or compile time? please explain your issue

Comment: Dear @BoboIrmuun. When one of my team members approach me with an argument like "I can't Access that method" or similar (It's not working etc.), I just turn them away and tell them to come back with specific details. If your code compiles, you are able to Access that method, UNLESS, you are deploying the service executable and not the assembly containing the mix_plan class. In that case, since the method is called inside a timer callback, your service will START ok, bu will fail when the callback is invoked, which is, after 10 seconds

Comment: I apologize for poor English language. Primarily I want to insert some data to couchbase in specified time using windows service. i have done something else (write to file specified time using that windows service). But i cant use ComputeNextDayPlan() or it not working. About the ComputeNextDayPlan() is no errors no problem just not working from windows service project. Thank you

Comment: @BoboIrmuun you need to figure out what is happening when computeNextDayPlan() is called. Setting a debugger on Timer_Elasped and stepping into the code is probably your best bet. You can also enable logging with the Couchbase SDK and see what gets written to log: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/sdk/dotnet/collecting-information-and-logging.html